# How to write a Javascript API wrapper

Tags: javascript, api, reactjs, wrapper

This is a question about how implement a Javascript wrapper in best way.
I'm coding a react client and i have a set of API.
These API returns a lot of datas that client don't needs.
What i want to do is to write a wrapper, an index.js where call API, get the response and re map it in order to exclude useless datas.
I know that isn't the best approch, but i have few days of work and this seems the faster solution.
What is the best way to do this? Or, better, what is the cleaner way to do this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you include an example of returned data, and the data that should be included and excluded from final result at Question?

Comment: Returned data are a lot. 
To make simple, the real question is about i can get the response (json) from my api (passing parameters).
After that, if i have the json, i'll make another json taking certains datas from json.

Comment: If you have a list of the property names of the objects that you want to filter you can use destructuring assignment.

Comment: Ok, now i'm using isomorphic-fetch to retrieve datas from api and after that i compose my new json object. Thanks for responses, send me on right way!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to [Normalizer](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr). It allows you to normalize some api responses and exclude useless data.